# Get audio source link from Website with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, asp.net, web-crawler

I am writing a script to fetch audio source links from a website. By crawling the main page a get a list of the links available. but when I crawl the links generated I can't find the source. (It should be inside href of a < audio > tag).

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getHTML(st):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(site+'/',timeout=100) as response:
        return response.read() 

site = 'http://www.e-radio.gr'
soup = BeautifulSoup(getHTML(site), 'html.parser')
# Parse Main Page And get links
lst = list()

for a in soup.body.find_all('a', {'class' : 'erplayer'}):
    item = a.get('href')
    if site in item:
        lst.append(item)
    else:
        lst.append(site + item)

print("\n".join(lst))
```

It seems that the website doesn't load properly and it doesn't load the audio source using urllib.request. What else i can use instead of urllib.request so it waits for the full page to load. What i have thought was to use some external web browser to generate the html but i don't know how to do that

Comment: can you post the html from where you need to get the link? the audio link html

Comment: The website link is in the code. This is all my code, you can run it

Comment: Right, but if we run the code, we see the audio links printed. What is the problem?..

Comment: Now I need to extract an < audio > block from each link and it is not in the html returned from the page as it should

Comment: http://www.e-radio.gr/Real-Fm-978-Athens-i680/live this is the href and i could not find any audio tag in the website

Comment: @Exprator ah, gotcha. So, when you follow the extracted links, you are not able to get to the actual audio content which you want to download?

Comment: You can use http://www.e-radio.gr/Rainbow-89-Thessaloniki-i92/live as a reference and try to find the audio

Comment: in this site also there is no audio tag bro

Comment: I want the link of the audio source so i can later give it vlc

Comment: load it in chrome. it is a radio page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but we can approach that step by step - first getting the player's HTML by following the `iframe` link. Then, getting the flash player link and following it. Then, extracting the link to the `mp3` and downloading the stream. All of that under the same web-scraping session:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def download_file(session, link, path):
    r = session.get(link, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r:
                f.write(chunk)


base_url = "http://www.e-radio.gr"
url = "http://www.e-radio.gr/Rainbow-89-Thessaloniki-i92/live"

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36'}
    response = session.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    frame = soup.find(id="playerControls1")
    frame_url = urljoin(base_url, frame["src"])

    response = session.get(frame_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    link = soup.select_one(".onerror a")['href']
    flash_url = urljoin(response.url, link)

    response = session.get(flash_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    mp3_link = soup.select_one("param[name=flashvars]")['value'].split("url=", 1)[-1]
    print(mp3_link)

    download_file(session, mp3_link, "download.mp3")
```